# only SOA on own DNS server; other RR on third DNS servers

Tags: domain-name-system, ns-record, tinydns

At Registro.br, I bought a domain and pointed to my primary DNS server.
I use tinydns.
I created a SOA and two NS entries. That's working perfectly.
My question:

Is it possible on my DNS server rewrite the SOA and NS entries and point to Amazon's Route 53 Servers and, from Route 53, manage other resource records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delegate subdomains to another DNS provider like Amazon by setting NS records for those subdomains and pointing them to Amazon.  But I don't think that's what you're asking.

If you want for some reason to point the whole zone to Amazon so that Amazon provides DNS for the domain, then the place to do this is at the registry.  Of course that means any records you've set up in tinydns, SOA, NS, A etc are irrelevant.

There are no standard NS entries for Amazon and you need to jump through their hoops before they tell you which ones to use.  Then enter those name servers into Registro.br, and complete the configuration at Amazon or whichever DNS provider you choose.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for help! I must change the dns pointer to Amazon at Registro.br...

Comment: By the way, one more question: Are www, pop, smtp, ftp, or what else considered as subdomains? Ex.: main domain: mydomain.com.br; subdomain: pop.mydomain.com.br ... ?

Comment: 'www.mydomain.com.br' is a subdomain of the main domain and could be delegated separately (although it's unusual to do so), 'pop.mydomain.com.br' is also a subdomain of 'mydomain.com.br'.  However, the MX record for sending to 'address@mydomain.com.br' is part of the main zone, whatever the value of that record.  Sorry if this is not a very good explanation.